# internal data structure of NSAttributedString?

Tags: objective-c, data-structures, subclass, nsattributedstring

I want to subclass NSAttributedString but I don't know how the internal storage looks like.
NSAttributedString is a subclass of NSObject. Most likely it uses NSString to store characters and another data structure to keep track of the attributes (e.g. color, font).

Attributes are stored in a NSDictionary are a valid for a certain character range (NSRange), but the attributes can also overlap in character range.

What kind of efficient data structure would be suitable for this? Storing a dictionary for every character is probably not the way to do it.

Edit: 
I don't know how more explicit I can be? I have my custom NSString subclass that does the things I want it to do. Now I want to add default attributes (color, font type, font size => NSFontAttributeName, NSForegroundColorAttributeName, etc.). I want to use my custom string in NSTextView or UITextView with my own custom NSTextStorage. NSTextStorage requires you to provide your own data property. I have the string, but I still need the text attributes.

Edit:
Why a custom NSAttributedString? I need my own custom NSString (no other way around it, I tried). This string has to be displayed to the user and that requires a NSAttributedString/NSTextStorage. So I also need to make a custom NSAttributedString.

Comment: Why don't you explain what you are trying to achieve. Then people can offer suggestions.

Comment: Array with special objects, that contain the range ans set of attributes, for example. Array may be [auto]sorted by start of range for fast lookup, for example. Or maybe tricky pure C structs. Why do you need to know about concrete implementation details?

Comment: Sounds like there are two totally independent questions here: "I want my attributed string to do *x*. How do I do it?" or "I want a data structure with *x* properties. What is it called?". It might be better to ask one of those two questions.

Comment: (otherwise, you're asking a question about the private implementation details of a class. To which the only good answer is: "whatever Apple feels like when they release a new framework version)

Comment: @everyone, I want to subclass NSAttributedString. I already have my  NSString subclass. Now I want to add attributes to it. But I don't know how to store the attributes (what kind of data structures) because I lack the CS knowledge. :(

Edit: how Apple does it, I leave to Apple. How can I do it?

Comment: @user965972 You need to tell us what exactly you wish to do. You are being too vague. Add what attributes? Why do you want to know the internal details (you shouldn't)? And put the details in your question, not in a comment.

Comment: Moved to question. (Sorry, I don't know all the rules here yet.)

Comment: Do you want to implement your own version of NSAttributedString? I think you should re-title your question. (Focus on the results you want rather than the implementation approach)

Comment: The important question is **why** you want to make your own subclass of `NSAttributedString`.  What additions or changes do you need to make to `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: @bneely, yes I want my own NSAttributesString subclass. I know which primitive methods to override. The result is a drop-in replacement for NSAttribtedString. My problem is with the internal representation of the attributes, hence the title.

Comment: I think it is a very good question and i want to know the same. 
I want to know first because i'm curious and because every implementation has tradeoffs.

Answer (score 1):

Define an array of attribute runs. Define attribute run as custom object with following properties: NSRange range and NSMutableDictionary *attributes. Override all the methods of NSAttributedString described in docs with your own implementation that looks in your array. Now you have custom attributed string class that is fully comparible with original and is subclass of it.

(Note that underlying logic may be hard to implement efficiently. If you tell what the big picture is, someone may present another/simpler way to solve your task)

Comment: That's it? No tree, hashes, maps,...? You are probably correct, but it seems so simple, too simple. (no offence intended) Would this also be efficient enough for an NSMutableAttributedString? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Can't tell whether I am correct or not until you define what is the task that must be solved efficiently. The solution presented is simplest among possible (it is memory-efficient and linear-access-potentially-efficient enough already). If you are about NSTextView - NSAttributedString protocol efficiency, please make your own research, how it is used exactly, as it is too complex to ask here on SO. I think the interface gives some cues already.

Comment: And do not forget that *premature optimization* without *profiling the proof-of-concept* solution is **nonsense**.

Answer (score 1):

[NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is [toll-free bridged](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Toll-FreeBridgin/Toll-FreeBridgin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH2) with [CFAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFAttributedString/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CFAttributedStringRef). CFAttributedString, in turn, is an opaque type. In neither case does Apple document or provide access to the internal data storage. So, there is no official source for the information you are requesting.

Comment: It's not officially documented but i've seen some comments from Apple engineers that there are multiple implementations based on the size of string etc. Unfortunately i'm unable to regoogle it

Comment: You may be referring to [class clusters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html)